# Error when changing the key name in json while receiving input from AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda

Below is the AWS lambda java code which is receiving the input which is coming from the AWS API Gateway. The java code below :

```java
    public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


        public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {

            LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
            logger.log("Loading Java Lambda handler of ProxyWithStream");


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
            String name = "World";
            String responseCode = "200";

            try {
                JSONObject event = (JSONObject)parser.parse(reader);
                if (event.get("queryStringParameters") != null) {
                    JSONObject qps = (JSONObject)event.get("queryStringParameters");
                    if ( qps.get("name") != null) {
                        name = (String)qps.get("name");
                    }
                    if (qps.get("httpStatus") != null) {
                        responseCode = qps.get("httpStatus)").toString();
                    }
                }
                //response.put("statusCode", responseCode);
                response.put("rohit", event.toJSONString());  

            } catch(ParseException pex) {
                response.put("statusCode", "400");
                response.put("exception", pex);
            }

            logger.log(response.toJSONString());
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
            writer.write(response.toJSONString());  
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

when I change the

```java
    response.put("body", event.toJSONString());
```

to

```java
    response.put("rohit", event.toJSONString());
```

it is showing error:

```java
    {
        "message": "Internal server error"
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advance...